# Expect script: How to set return value of a command to a variable and exit from script if the return value is not 0?

Tags: linux, tcl, expect

I am running a command in expect script and I want to exit the expect script if command return value is not 0. I set the variable ret to "$?" like this, which is not working:

```
send "./$SCRIPT_NAME >> out.txt &\r"
expect "~#"
set ret $?
if { $ret != 0} {
    exit $ret
}
```

But I get this output:

```
expected integer but got "$?"
    while executing
"exit $ret"
    invoked from within
"if { $ret != 0} {
    exit $ret
}"
```

What is the equivalent of $? in expect?

Comment: Expect is not a sh-like shell. Expect uses [Tcl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tclsh) and Tcl's `$?` does not mean the same as shell's `$?`.

Comment: I fixed your misspellings of "except/expect".

Comment: Yes, I would gladly accept a help though. What is the expect equivalent?

Comment: You can't get the exit code of a process until after it exits. Don't background the subprocess if you want to do this the easy way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit of a pain in expect.

Firstly, since you need to get the exit status, you don't want to launch the script in the background. You'd have to use the shell's `wait` command anyway to get the exit status.

Next, you have to ask the shell to print out the exit status and capture that with the `expect` command. Note that expect returns `\r\n` for line endings.

```
send "./$SCRIPT_NAME >> out.txt; echo $?\r"

expect -re {(\d+)\r\n~#}
# ..........^^^^^
# exit status is captured in the 1st set of parens

set ret $expect_out(1,string)
if { $ret != 0} {
    exit $ret
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution and I got : 
 ./hello_world >> out.txt; echo $?
0
can't read "expect_out(1,string)": no such element in array
 while executing
"set ret $expect_out(1,string)".
Can you think of any solution?

Comment: Show the `expect` command you used: Did you use the `-re` option? If you did, run the script with `expect -d script_name.exp` to enable verbose debugging. It will show why the pattern did not match

Comment: I used -d and got this output:
./scriptname>> out.txt; echo $?\r\n255\r\n<s/path/scriptname/build# " (spawn_id exp3) match regular expression "(\d+)\r\n~#"? Gate "*\r\n~#"? gate=no
expect: timed out
can't read "expect_out(1,string)": no such element in array
while executing
"set ret $expect_out(1,string)"

Comment: OK, your prompt is not literally `~#` -- you can use `expect -re {(\d+)\r\n[^\n]+# $}`